# Merge dictionaries with old keys when old value and new key is same

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to merge two dictionaries like this:

```
old={'a':'1a','b':'1b','c':'1c'}
new={'1a':'c','1b':'d','1c':'e'}
```

I want output like this:

```
new_dict={'a':'c','b':'d','c':'e'}
```

Note: The length of both dictionaries is different.

How to do it in python?

Comment: Because the answers differ I thought you need to clarify the question a bit especially because you say the dictionaries have different sizes: What should happen to the values that aren't present in the `new` dict? i.e. what would be the output if `old={'a':'1a','b':'1b','c':'1c', 'd': '1d'}`? Should it be still `{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e'}` or `{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'd': None}` or even `{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'd': '1d'}`?

Comment: **Quote your strings please.** Also are you sure that all lists have exactly one element in your problem?

Comment: That doesn't make sense anymore. `list('1a')` will be `['1', 'a']` - how should that match the key `'1a'` from the second dict?

Comment: I rolled back the question. If you have a working and representative example please edit the question again but rather have a not-representative example than the not-working example.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the new dictionary using a dictionary comprehension where you get the values from the new dictionary based on the keys in the old dictionary.  Be sure to use `get` which returns `None` by default if a value from the old dictionary is not present as a key in the new dictionary.

```
old = {'a': '1a', 'b': '1b' ,'c': '1c'}
new = {'1a': 'c', '1b': 'd', '1c': 'e'}

new_dict = {k: new.get(old[k]) for k in old}
>>> new_dict
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e'}
```

Comment: `.get` uses `(` instead of `[`. Great solution though!

Comment: also you can drop `.keys()`, also I dislike the idea of accessing the value by key when `.items()` does that.

Comment: @Jitesh Make sure you're using curly brackets and not square brackets

Comment: What if I have list in new dictionary ?

Comment: @Jitesh Update your question and include the part where you have a list in your dictionaries (and what you want to happen there). :)

Comment: @Jitesh Which one? Keys from old or values from new? You cannot have a list as a key in a dictionary, so it would only work if the list is in the values of the new dictionary.

Comment: @Alexander keys cannot be `list`s. OP is probably massively confused.

Answer (score 2):

With a dict-comprehension:

```
old = {'a': '1a','b': '1b','c': '1c'}
new = {'1a': 'c','1b': 'd','1c': 'e'}

res = {k: new[v] for k, v in old.items()}             # if all values in `old` exist in `new` as keys.
res = {k: new.get(v, None) for k, v in old.items()}   # if you cannot guarantee the above.
print(res)  # {'b': 'd', 'a': 'c', 'c': 'e'}
```

*Note that the `None` parameter of the `.get()` method is the default one and as such, it can be omitted. I will leave it there though to remind you that you can specify anything you want depending on the specifics of your problem (e.g., `''` (blank string) might be better in your case)

Comment: forget `,None`, as this is the default arg

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That is a good point but having it there probably reminds people that they can choose something else instead depending on their requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension that interprets the value of the first dictionary as the key of the second dictionary:

```
>>> {item: new[value] for item, value in old.items() if value in new}
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e'}
```

In case you can garantuee that all values of `old` are in `new` you could omit the `if value in new` part.